# Lally column supporting 1st floor

Tags: support

I've got 5 2x8x21's as a support beam for the 1st load.. The second floor joist are running the other way and using the same pillar as one end of the 21' 2x8's..  There's a lolli pole at 10' from the wall.. Could I move it to 15'?? It's supporting the floor between a living room and a bedroom.

Comment: It's unlikely that you should trust a bunch of well-meaning individuals to second-guess the engineering that went into an investment as large as a house. PS, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lally_column

Comment: You and I may have Lally Columns - I'm assuming Pat has a white fiberboard column with a 3 foot diameter disk of hard candy you can lick for a very long time on it. Regardless of that, moving a column without the advice of a structural engineer is a good way to make your house fall down, generally - even if the column is actually concrete filled steel with no candy like the rest of us have.

Comment: No. (See above). No. (But if you get an engineer, he or she may tell you how to get to *yes*.)